# structuring my app so lat and long coords are available in controller

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a controller which contains the code below.  I'm finding that the rest of my code is being run before the code below returns.

How can I best structure my code so that the lat and long coords will be available to the rest of my code in the controller?

I'm thinking I could put the code below in the run block and assign the lat and long to `$rootScope` but I'd prefer not to do that.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
var self = this;
  $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition({timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true}).then(
  function(position){
    self.latitude1 = position.coords.latitude;
    self.longitude1 = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log(position.coords.latitude);
    console.log(position.coords.longitude);
  },
  function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });
});
```

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Use a service to save the promise that the `$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition` function returns and use the `.then` method to delay code that depends on those coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the promise:

```
var positionPromise = $ionicPlatform.ready()
    .then (function() {
         //return to chain
         return $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(config);
    }).catch (function (error) {
         console.log(error);
         //throw to chain error
         throw error;
    });
```

Elsewhere, use the promise:

```
positionPromise.then(function (position) {
    console.log(position);
    //PUT delayed code here
    //...
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: That looks like it should do the job.  When you say "use a service to save the promise", do you mean that I should create a factory or something and add that first body of code to it, inject it into the controller and use the second piece of code?  I've added the code as is to my controller and its not quite working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using the above answer I got this working with this:

```
app.factory('geoService', function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaGeolocation) {

  var positionOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};

  return {
    getPosition: function() {
      return $ionicPlatform.ready()
        .then(function() {
          return $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionOptions);
        })
    }
  };
});
```

Then injecting the factory into my controller and using it like this:

```
geoService.getPosition()
  .then(function(position) {
    // code the depends on the position coords.
  })
```